# Define Index types with a specific pattern for typescript

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

is there a way to define Index types for typescript with a specific pattern? something like all properties starting with "$" are HTMLElements.
something like

```
[key: "^\$.+"]: HTMLElement;
```

Comment: Not currently possible

Answer (score 1):

**No, this is currently not possible**, [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) are limited to the following:

> There are two types of supported index signatures: string and number. It is possible to support both types of indexers, but the type returned from a numeric indexer must be a subtype of the type returned from the string indexer. This is because when indexing with a number, JavaScript will actually convert that to a string before indexing into an object.

There are [some proposals](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/6579#issuecomment-261519733) for allowing exactly what you described, but no significant effort for an implementation has happend yet.